# MS Access Top 5 Query multiple criteria grouped by month and area

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I would like to use the top 5 to capture the top 5 for a number of criteria.

The data style is month date, area1, subarea1, sub areas2 etc etc, type, unique identifier for each row.

What I'm trying to do is for each month and for area find the top 5 types.

Sample Data:

```
Date              Division        Sub Division       ID 
31/05/2012        Sales                              001
31/05/2012        Sales           Call Centre        002
31/05/2012        Sales           Call Centre        003
31/05/2012        Sales           Store              004
31/05/2012        Marketing                          005
31/05/2012        Marketing        TV                006
30/04/2012        Sales                              001
30/04/2012        Sales           Call Centre        002
30/04/2012        Sales           Call Centre        003
30/04/2012        Sales           Store              004
30/04/2012        Marketing                          005
30/04/2012        Marketing        TV                006
```

And so on.

The output I'm after is:
Top 5 at Division level (no consideration of Sub Division) for each month
Top 5 at each Sub-Division level for each month

Sample Output:

`Date          Top5Areas     Volume
31/05/2012    Sales         100
31/05/2012    Marketing     90
31/05/2012    HR            50
30/04/2012    Sales         100
30/04/2012    Marketing     90
30/04/2012    HR            50`

And depending on the level the sub division for the respective area:

`Date          Top5Areas     Volume
31/05/2012    Call Centre   100
31/05/2012    Store         90
31/05/2012    HR            50` 

but with 5 for each group.

I'm not should how to do this and wonder if I'll need to build up the result through a number of queries or whether there is a better way.

Thanks in advance and appreciate your suggestions.

`SELECT [TableA].[DisplayVar] AS DisplayVar, [TableB].[Date] AS MonthDate, TableC.        [Divison] AS Divison, Volume
    FROM (SELECT [TableA].[DisplayVar],
    [TableB].[Date],
    TableC.[Divison],
    Volume
      (  SELECT  COUNT() + 1
      FROM    (   SELECT [TableA].[DisplayVar], [TableB].[Date], TableC.[Divison], COUNT()     AS Volume
         FROM    ([TableA] INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].[ID] = [TableB].[ID]) LEFT JOIN     TableC ON [TableB].ID = TableC.Descriptor
         GROUP BY [TableA].[DisplayVar], [TableB].[Date], TableC.[Divison]
      ) AS T
      WHERE   T.[TableB].[Date] = Data.[TableB].[Date]
      AND     T.Volume > Data.Volume
    ) AS Rank
    FROM    (   SELECT  [TableA].[DisplayVar], [TableB].[Date], TableC.[Divison], COUNT(*)     AS Volume
      FROM    ([TableA] INNER JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].[ID] = [TableB].[ID]) LEFT JOIN     TableC ON [TableB].ID = TableC.Descriptor
      WHERE   [TableB].[Date] BETWEEN Date() AND DateADD("m", -12, Date())

    GROUP BY[TableA].[DisplayVar], [TableB].[Date], TableC.[Divison]
    ) AS DATA
    )  AS Data
    WHERE (((Data.Rank)<=5))
    ORDER BY [TableB].[Date] DESC , Volume DESC;`

Comment: good point. would be the count/frequency of the division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do a top n per date (Which is what I think you are after) in access is to use a correlated subquery. I think the simplest method is similar to using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in other DBMS, it adds an additional field to your orignal aggregate query giving each division/date a rank, the the outer most where clause limits it to rows where the rank is less than or equal to 5.

```
SELECT  Date,
        Division,
        Volume
FROM    (   SELECT  Date,
                    Division,
                    Volume,
                    (   SELECT  COUNT(*) + 1
                        FROM    (   SELECT  Date, Division, COUNT(*) AS Volume
                                    FROM    YourTable
                                    GROUP BY Date, Division
                                ) AS T
                        WHERE   T.Date = Data.Date
                        AND     T.Volume > Data.Volume
                    ) AS Rank
            FROM    (   SELECT  Date, Division, COUNT(*) AS Volume
                        FROM    YourTable
                        WHERE   Date BETWEEN DATE() AND DATEADD("m", -12, DATE())
                        GROUP BY Date, Division
                    ) AS DATA
        ) AS Data
WHERE   Rank <= 5
```

The downfall (or benefit depending on your requirements) of this is that it does not deal with ties, i.e if you had 10 divisions with the same volume all 10 would be returned, not just 5 of them.

I am not sure if this is exactly what you require, but hopefully will is at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks GarethD. Looking at the first code now. But realised I need a period condition on the date field for instance: HAVING ((([Table].[Date]) Between Date() And DateAdd("m",-12,Date()))) But think there are issues with having and a order by

Comment: Use `WHERE` not `HAVING` since Date is in the group by list there is no need to use `HAVING`. I've made an edit both queries to show this.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the WHERE   Volume >= ( SELECT  MIN(Volume) on the first example working, but hopeful it will work out. Just to confirm the 'T' on the line - FROM    YourTable is an error?

Comment: Just realised the top query will not work. The T was there because the query was supposed to have the clause `WHERE T.Date = Data.Date` however it appears you cannot reference `data` from with a subquery within a correlated subquery. This means the second query is your best option. If the second query works for you let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The second query works well, I did add a simple order by. The only things I need to work out is my table relationships. Division from tableA, Date from tableB and need to display other things from table C. Thanks for your help

Comment: One last question, after adding my table relationships the volume column is empty in the output. It appears to be identifying the top 5 correctly. On running the query I receive an 'enter parameter value - volume' box. Looks like it doesn't relate the volume to data, but I've tried data.volume with no luck.

Comment: Can you edit your question or post a new question to show the query you are trying to run and your table relations. I will then take a look and try and work out why volume isn't being mapped correctly.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, provided my code above. Trying to get volume and now rank in the output.

Comment: I can't see any issue with your current query other than you are missing a comma after `Volume` before the subquery that retrieves the rank. It could be worth creating a query that outputs `Date, Division, Volume` then substituting this query into the larger query to simplify the final query.

Comment: Can't believe I missed the comma, perfect now! Just need to work on getting the rank to come through (will need to be part of the identifier in the final output) getting a 'query to complex' message at present.